# Students changing the result of an investigation

Tags: research-process, ethics, reference-request, research-topic

It is common to see students at the laboratory (electronics, specifically), altering the values or disregarding them trivially just because the values won't fit into the other data, instead of reporting and documenting them and disregarding them using a proper (statistical is an option) method. Disregarding the data almost randomly could lead to misinterpretation of it, and loss of important information and knowledge for the student.

On the other hand, when the laboratory practice is similar (or the same) to the old semester one, they will just come into the lab to show they are present (and avoid being marker as absent), and ask the students of the previous semester for the data and document it that way.

- How can one deal with this type of students?
- Is there a book/guide for some sort of "Research Ethics" that deals with these kind of issues and could provide more examples and situations like these?

> *(This could be out of topic depending on how the reader see it)* 
>
>  There are another less common examples, like when a student reads an article and when referencing, instead of citing only this article, cites this article and the articles cited in this article, like if he read them all.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't mean it that way, but a general process, you already made it clear I should stick to my institution codes. I just removed that item because I just realize it sounds too severe.

Answer (score 5):

You know the answer to your question: This is unethical research conduct, and you need to talk about what is *ethical* in your class and in your lab sessions.

What is ethical and unethical is not inherently *obvious*. We have resolved that certain things are ethical/unethical because we care about *truth*, and we have seen over centuries of doing science that certain things (like omitting data points that don't fit a preconception) distracts us from finding truth. But that is a historical perspective students don't have without education. So educate them.